# View list of new modules added to linux kernel source code

Tags: kernel, compiling

My first compile and I would like to ask if there is any way to list ONLY NEW CHANGES added to my kernel source code.

I am asking because I have just added cx2072x codec to 4.19.1 kernel and I'm about to compile and I'm setting up the .config file.

I have found this change and set it as M module but I am wondering if there are other things newly added to review.

I'm using a kernel configuration menu accessed by 'make nconfig' in the root of source code.

I would prefer to stick to this menu rather than looking into text codes.

Thank you for your suggestions.